Reactive form custom directives not run OnInit or when hidden input shown by *ngIf
Using reactive forms in Angular I created two directives one that converts values from cents to dollars by dividing by 100, and one that converts dollars to cents by multiplying by 100.  This works when I manually set the form controls, but it doesn't get applied OnInit, and it doesn't get applied when a form input is shown when hidden behind an *ngIf.
I created a stackblitz with an example.  It should OnInit show $12,345.50 but it instead shows $12,34550.00 and the same value when a form field is shown until they are manually set using the buttons.  Example is in Angular v15, but I'm using v18 if that helps with a solution, but able to replicate it similarly in either.
Is there a way to have the directives run OnInit and when the input is shown? Or should I be implementing this differently?

"The OnInit interface has a hook method named ngOnInit(). If you implement this method in your component or directive class, Angular calls it shortly after checking the input properties for that component or directive for the first time." So in your directive implement OnInit and they will be invoked at that time.

We can access the NgControl directive and directly patch the transformed value on first load.
Also, do not use *ngIf when working with hiding forms. It makes the controls not work properly, since it's destroyed from DOM; always go for [hidden] attribute instead:
import { AfterContentInit, Directive, Input, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  DefaultValueAccessor,
  FormControlName,
  NgControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  maskitoNumberOptionsGenerator,
  maskitoParseNumber,
} from '@maskito/kit';

export const dollarMask = maskitoNumberOptionsGenerator({
  min: 0,
  // Maximum to avoid floating point precision errors
  // which will occur when numeric values are too large
  // exceeding Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
  max: 1000000000,
  precision: 2,
  decimalSeparator: '.',
  decimalZeroPadding: true,
  thousandSeparator: ',',
  prefix: '$',
});

@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[maskito][toDollars]',
})
export class ToDollarsDirective {
  private readonly accessor = inject(DefaultValueAccessor, { self: true });
  private readonly formControlName = inject(NgControl, { self: true });

  ngOnInit() {
    const initialValue = this.formControlName.value;
    const dollars1 = initialValue != null ? initialValue / 100 : initialValue;
    this.formControlName.control!.patchValue(dollars1);
  }

  ngOnAfterContentInit() {
    const original = this.accessor.writeValue.bind(this.accessor);
    this.accessor.writeValue = (value: any) => {
      const dollars = value != null ? value / 100 : value;
      original(dollars);
    };
  }
}

@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[maskito][toCents]',
})
export class ToCentsDirective {
  private readonly accessor = inject(DefaultValueAccessor, { self: true });
  private readonly formControlName = inject(NgControl, { self: true });


  ngAfterContentInit() {
    const original = this.accessor.onChange.bind(this.accessor);
    this.accessor.onChange = (value: any) => {
      const cents = maskitoParseNumber(value) * 100;
      original(cents);
    };
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks, that was super helpful!  I noticed that the toCents directive seems to effect validations on the input.  Is there something that can be added to the directive so it doesn't interfere with the validations?
